# TensorFlow issues with @tf.function while training , saving, loading the encoder-decoder model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am working on developing a neural machine translation system using the Seq2Seq model.
I followed this tutorial from TensorFlow

https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/networks_seq2seq_nmt

After training the model I want to save the model and use the model elsewhere, Whoever I am facing the following issues with the usages of @tf.function.

1. #USING THE @tf.function in the decoder gives the error in training

   TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
   a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
   leak out of the function building context by including a
   tf.init_scope in your function building code.
   For example, the following function will fail:
   @tf.function
   def has_init_scope():
   my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
   with tf.init_scope():
   added = my_constant * 2
   The graph tensor has name: LuongAttention/memory_layer/Tensordot:0
2. #NOT USING THE @tf.function in the decoder trains the model but gives the error in saving

   AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references untracked resource Tensor("LuongAttention/memory_layer/Tensordot:0", shape=(32, 11, 1024), dtype=float32).TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be tracked by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly.

   Trackable Python objects referring to this tensor (from gc.get_referrers, limited to two hops):
   <tensorflow_addons.seq2seq.attention_wrapper.LuongAttention object at 0x7fad2f922590>
3. #NOT USING THE @tf.function in the decoder trains the model and running the model once, saves the model but gives the error after loading

   TypeError: The argument 'cell' (<tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model.load.AttentionWrapper object at 0x7facd7bb59d0>) is not an RNNCell: 'output_size' property is missing, 'state_size' property is missing, 'get_initial_state' method is required.

here is the code to replicate the error: google colab link

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ktxyOCHZe_QZ92Nk4lqujfhnvWc4YH0s?usp=sharing

Any pointers in this direction are highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I would suggest you check the issues page on the tensorflow github, and possibly post your issue there

Comment: Suer, I have opened the issue here:https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2464
Thank you for your time